# Guaranteeing my container of pointers memory exists later?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code like this:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, A*> MAP;
MAP _map;

int myMethod(){
    B b;
    const int key = 4;
    addToMap(key, b);
}

void addToMap(const int i, B& b){
     MAP::accessor a;
    _map.insert(a, MAP::value_type(I, &b));
}
```

I am worried the `B` object created on the stack won't exist in my map once `myMethod()` has returned. I also cannot change the interface of MAP easily because it is used in so many places.

What can I do to `addToMap()`, to guarantee my map element isn't deleted after `myMethod()` returns?

Could I force inserting a copy of B?

Comment: You can create it on the heap. Just don't forget to delete it afterwards.

Comment: Is `std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<A>>` a too big change ?

Comment: @Jarod42 this can be thought of as library code and I'm not the one creating the B objects. As I understood it, I cannot assign existing objects to unique_ptrs if they're on the stack? I can only assign heap memory to them, except I don't know if they're on the heap or stack because that's outside the interface?

Comment: please test your code before posting.

Comment: If you store the object itself instead of a pointer, the map will make a copy so that it doesn't matter if the original is destroyed.

Comment: @MarkRansom that idea sounds the best to me. When map::erase() is called, would that delete the element?

Comment: @mezamorphic If you can change the typedef to `typedef std::unordered_map<int, A> MAP;` then yes, `map::erase()` will delete the element itself.  Alternatively, change the typedef to `typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<A>> MAP`, then addToMap needs to become `_map.insert(a, MAP::value_type(i, std::make_unique(b));`

Comment: Basically you need to sort out how the memory management is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `B` provides a copy-constructor.

Therefore :

- you can't modify the `typedef std::unordered_map<int, A*> MAP;`
- your actual map is supposed to have ownership on objects on which it hold a pointer to,
- `B` inherits from `A` (which could explain why the author of the original code uses pointers in `MAP`)

You could use this code :

```
// it's useless to pass an int by reference,     
// and you should pass b by const ref
void addToMap(int i, const B& b){
   auto old =  _map[i]; // if _map[i] doesn't exist, insert nullptr, 
                        // if it does, return old value.
   delete old; // if old doesn't exist, old == nullptr
   _map[i] = new B(b);
}
```

This code is good if (and only if) `B(const B& b)` doesn't throw. If it does, `_map` will contain an invalid value (nullptr), but no memory will be leaked.

However, you should be careful in your other methods to properly destroy objects pointed by the map when they are removed from it.
Besides, you should destroy remaining objects in the destructor of your enclosing object (the one who hold the map).

Finally, if you can, you should follow suggestions which say that you could use `unique_ptr`. If your legacy code is poorly designed in matters of ownership, perhaps a map with `shared_ptr` is a better option.